# Laravel query builder duplicates row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm printing some data in mi index.blade.php file but it returns duplicated values. This is my query:

```
$hist = DB::table('codigo_sisnova')
            ->join('llamada', 'codigo_sisnova.idPaciente', '=', 'llamada.id_paciente')
            ->join('medico', 'llamada.id_medico', '=', 'medico.id_medico')
            ->where('llamada.status_llamada', 'Finalizada')
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->where('llamada.status_pago', '=', 'Sisnova')
                ->orWhere('llamada.status_pago', '=', 'RedireccionadaSisnova');
            })
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

I already tried with **unique()** but it doesn't work too.

**EDIT**

The relations between tables are one to may from "codigo_sisnova" to "llamada", if I take out the join with the table "medico" the rows keep duplicating

Every row gets a duplicate

Comment: Need a bit more info, I think. What are the relationships (one to many, many to many, etc.) between the tables you're joining, and what values are duplicated that you weren't expecting?

Comment: I just added that info.

Comment: `->distinct('column_name');` try this

Answer (score 0):

You will have multiple `codigo_sisnova` rows if you are joining tables that have multiple matches on that table. `DISTINCT` would not eliminate those since the joined data will make it non-distinct in those results. I would recommend trying to use `groupBy()` to eliminate the redundant rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the group_by statement. Assuming that you have an ID column in codigo_sisnova, besides adding it in a SELECT clause, you need to add it before your get() method :

```
$hist = DB::table('codigo_sisnova')
        ->select('codigo_sisnova.id')
        ->join('llamada', 'codigo_sisnova.idPaciente', '=', 'llamada.id_paciente')
        ->join('medico', 'llamada.id_medico', '=', 'medico.id_medico')
        ->where('llamada.status_llamada', 'Finalizada')
        ->where(function($query){
            $query->where('llamada.status_pago', '=', 'Sisnova')
            ->orWhere('llamada.status_pago', '=', 'RedireccionadaSisnova');
        })
        ->group_by('codigo_sisnova.id')
        ->get();
```